# Celery chains: Is it necessary to wait before getting the results?

Tags: python-3.x, celery, worker, celery-task

So, I have a chain of tasks in Python 3 that a celery worker runs. Currently, I use the following piece of code to get and print the final result of the chain :

```
while not result.ready():
    pass
print(result.get())
```

I have run the code with and without the *while-loop*, and it seems that the *while-loop* is redundant.

My question is: "is it necessary to have that *while-loop*?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by redundant, you mean that the code works fine without the while loop, then I would venture to say that the loop is not necessary. If, however, you throw an error without the loop because you're trying to print something that doesn't exist yet, then you should keep it. This can be a problem, though, because an empty while loop means you're just checking the same variable as fast as your computer can physically handle it, which tends to eat up your CPU. I recommend something like the following:

```
import time

t = 1 #The number of seconds you want to wait between checking if the result is ready

while not result.ready():
    time.sleep(t)
print(result.get())
```

You can set `t` to whatever makes sense. If the task you're running takes several hours, maybe set it to 60, and you'll get the result within a minute. If you want the result faster, you can make the interval smaller. This will keep the program from dragging down the rest of your computer. However, if you don't mind your fans blowing and you absolutely need to know the moment the result is ready, ignore all of the above and leave your code the way it is :)